# Deriving the density function of $\frac{X}{Y}$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, density-function

Given that the multivariate random variables ($A_1, A_2, A_3$) have a standard Gaussian on $\mathbb{R}^3$, and a matrix be defined as

$$M= \begin{pmatrix} \sqrt2A_1 &A_3 \\ A_3 & \sqrt2A_2 \end{pmatrix}$$.

Let $X = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2$ and $Y = \alpha_1 - \alpha_2$ where  $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are the eigenvalues of the matrix M with  $\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2$.

How do I find the density function of $\frac{X}{Y}$?

I tried to find the eigenvalues for $M$ using $det(M - \alpha I) = 0$, and I got

$$\alpha_1 = \frac{\sqrt2A_1 + \sqrt2A_2 + \sqrt{2A_1^2-4A_1A_2+2A_2^2+4A_3^2}}{2}$$
$$\alpha_2 = \frac{\sqrt2A_1 + \sqrt2A_2 - \sqrt{2A_1^2-4A_1A_2+2A_2^2+4A_3^2}}{2}$$
$$\frac{X}{Y} = \sqrt\frac{1}{A_1^2-2A_1A_2+A_2^2+2A_3^2}\biggl(A_1+A_2\biggr)$$

How do I derive the density from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $A_1,A_2,A_3$ are independent standard normal.

Going by your work,

$$\frac{X}{Y}=\frac{A_1+A_2}{\sqrt{(A_1-A_2)^2+2A_3^2}}=\frac{(A_1+A_2)/\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{A_1-A_2}{\sqrt 2}\right)^2+A_3^2}}$$

Change variables $\begin{pmatrix}A_1 \\ A_2 \\ A_3\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}U \\ V \\ W\end{pmatrix}$ such that

$$\begin{pmatrix}U \\ V \\ W\end{pmatrix}=
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt 2} & \frac1{\sqrt 2}&0
\\ \frac1{\sqrt 2} & -\frac1{\sqrt 2}&0
\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}}_B
\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 \\ A_2 \\ A_3\end{pmatrix}$$

Note that $B$ is an orthogonal matrix, which means

$$\begin{pmatrix}
A_1 \\ A_2 \\ A_3\end{pmatrix}\sim N_3(\mathbf 0,I_3)\implies \begin{pmatrix}
U \\ V \\ W\end{pmatrix}
\sim N_3(\mathbf 0,BB^T=I_3),
$$

In other words, $U,V,W$ are also independent standard normal.

It is easy to see that $U=\frac{A_1+A_2}{\sqrt 2}, V=\frac{A_1-A_2}{\sqrt 2}$ are standard normal, and that both of them are independent of $W=A_3$. The key is to prove the independence of $U$ and $V$. So if you are not comfortable with the orthogonal transformation above, argue that $U$ and $V$ are jointly normal and that they are uncorrelated. This would imply their independence.

Now $V^2,W^2$ are independent $\chi^2_1$ variables, so that $V^2+W^2 \sim \chi^2_2$, which is again independent of $U$. Thus, $T=\frac{U}{\sqrt{(V^2+W^2)/2}}$ has a $t$ distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom.

And of course,

$$\frac{X}{Y}=\frac{U }{\sqrt{V^2+W^2}}=\frac{T}{\sqrt 2} $$

Comment: Hi, do you mind explaining a bit on the change of variable method? And also is it possible to show this as a function of $f_\frac{X}{Y}(x,y)$? Thanks!

Comment: And also how is it proportional to a t-distribution?

Comment: If $\boldsymbol X$ is a multivariate normal vector with mean vector $0$ and dispersion matrix identity, and $\boldsymbol Y=B\boldsymbol X$ where $B$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $\boldsymbol Y$ has the same distribution as $\boldsymbol X$. You can show this by writing down joint densities and finding jacobian etc. As for why $t$ distribution, please check the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution#As_the_distribution_of_a_test_statistic) of a $t$ distribution. Once you identify the distribution, what's the big deal about writing the density function?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you mean. How did you end up with Y having the same distribution as X?

Comment: Check my edit for an alternative approach.